# Remove ehcache:jar:1.2.3 in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, ehcache

I have issue in multiple version of **ehcache** .So when I run the test cases I have the below error .so I googled to find for removing the ehcache 1.2.3 to solve the issue .So i run the dependency to find the reference of 1.2.3 below is the dependency tree .Pls suggest to remove the ehcache:jar:1.2.3 from the dependency tree .I tried in the below but didn't removed in the dependency tree .Pls suggest to fix the issue.

---

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:17: Element <defaultCache> does not allow attribute "maxElementsOnDisk".
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:147)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

---

+- com.shc.automation:cars-dao-framework:jar:1.0:test

[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:test

[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test

[INFO] |  +- db2jcc:db2jcc:jar:9.7.4:test

[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:test

[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.7.ga:test

[INFO] |  |  - net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:test

[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:test

[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:test

[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.29:test

[INFO] |  - cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:test

---

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shc.automation</groupId>
        <artifactId>cars-dao-framework</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>net.sf.ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: try giving `<groupId>XXX</groupId>`also

Comment: Pls answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Inside my pom the ehcache was loaded by org.apache.camel

This worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cache</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
          <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```